# Problem using Emgu.CV.Dnn SegmentationModel in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, emgucv, onnx, yolov8

I am trying to use the pre-trained YOLO v8 segmentation model (converted to ONNX format), in the C# programming language to find the mask of an object in an image. I'm using the Emgu.CV.Dnn namespace to read the pre-trained Yolo model. The problem occurs when I try to call the Segment method from the created SegmentationModel object, which causes an "OpenCV: outs.size() == 1" exception (Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.dll). I use Emgu.Cv version 4.8.1.5350. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of the program I tried to run:

```
try
{
    var img = CvInvoke.Imread(@"C:\data\1.jpg", ImreadModes.Color);
    var modelpath = @"C:\data\yolov8n-seg.onnx";
    var net = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromONNX(modelpath);
    
    var mdl=new SegmentationModel(net);
    mdl.SetPreferableBackend(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Backend.OpenCV);
    mdl.SetPreferableTarget(Target.Cpu);
    mdl.SetInputSwapRB(true);
    mdl.SetInputScale(1);
   
    VectorOfMat output = new VectorOfMat();
    VectorOfMat msk = new VectorOfMat();
    
    mdl.Predict(img, output); //this method works 
    mdl.Segment(img,msk);//this method throws an exception 

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**mdl.Predict** method works, but **mdl.Segment** does not.

Comment: The error is not super clear, but I would guess the `msk` output array  has the incorrect size/depth/shape, and openCVs type model is very permissive. The resulting mask should be another image, so try using a image-type for your `msk` parameter.

Comment: I have tried **Image<Gray, byte> msk = new Image<Gray,byte>(640, 640);** and **Image<Bgr, byte> msk = new Image<Bgr, byte>(640, 640);** but result is the same.

Comment: I would try something like `Image<Gray,float>`, since the result should be a probability, and that is usually described with float/double. If that does not work I have no idea.

Comment: The same error, when using **float** or **double**